# Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE

Tags: kernel, udev, bluetooth, error-handling

I used `journalctl -p 3 -xb`

and got this error message

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-06-23 22:48:08 AST, end at Sat 2016-06-25 13:15:23 AST. --
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x1, key code 152): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x2, key code 236): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x3, key code 142): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x4, key code 238): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x6, key code 227): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x7, key code 191): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x8, key code 194): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0xb, key code 205): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0xf, key code 225): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x10, key code 224): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x11, key code 228): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x13, key code 372): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x14, key code 115): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x15, key code 114): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x16, key code 113): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x17, key code 148): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:35 Almoullim systemd-udevd[268]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event14' (scan code 0x1a, key code 190): Invalid argument
Jun 25 09:31:36 Almoullim kernel: [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
Jun 25 09:31:36 Almoullim kernel: [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
Jun 25 09:31:37 Almoullim bluetoothd[572]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 25 09:31:37 Almoullim bluetoothd[572]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 25 09:31:37 Almoullim bluetoothd[572]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 25 09:31:46 Almoullim ntpd[933]: bind(21) AF_INET6 fe80::fbf4:15f0:61ef:15bd%3#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Jun 25 09:31:46 Almoullim ntpd[933]: unable to create socket on wlp3s0 (5) for fe80::fbf4:15f0:61ef:15bd%3#123
Jun 25 09:31:47 Almoullim ntpd[933]: bind(24) AF_INET6 fe80::fbf4:15f0:61ef:15bd%3#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Jun 25 09:31:47 Almoullim ntpd[933]: unable to create socket on wlp3s0 (6) for fe80::fbf4:15f0:61ef:15bd%3#123
```

How can i fix these errors?